# how to fetch particular row values table element after clicking a particular row in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

[this is table after clicking on date i want this date in php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxoIz.png)

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to fetch table values of a particular row by clicking on that in php and i want those values in php becasuse i want to fetch the data from database table using those values and displaying the data which get from database in table in same page

Comment: Please step to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :) But keep in mind that SO is a community that helps, and no one will do all the work for you. Please show us some code you messed up with and we'll be glad to help improve it...

Comment: after clicking particular row i want the row values in php

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what your needs are. Any sample of code you already tried that would clear that up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".table_row").click(function(e){
    var value=$(e.target).text();
    alert(value);
  });
});
```

Ashok, try this one, i think it works for you but it will give one value on a row where you clicked on it.

Comment: if i click on a row i want to fetch all values of that particular row.